# 2012-gon- subsets of vertices.

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Can we prove or disprove this?

For a sufficiently large $n$, every set of at least $ n$ points in the plane with no three collinear has a subset that form the vertices of a convex $2012$-gon.

Gerry mentions the Happy Ending theorem but I don't see how it relates. If someone could show me the steps in the proof or disproof, that would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the theorem of Erdos and Szekeres (sometimes known as "The Happy Ending Theorem").

The statement of the theorem, with some discussion, is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Ending_problem). There is also a link there to the [original paper](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=CM_1935__2__463_0).

Comment: Could you show how?

Comment: Are you familiar with the theorem? Have you tried to find it and read it and see what it says?

Comment: Yes, but I don't quite see how it relates.

Comment: Quoting from the paper: "Can we find for a given $n$ a number $N(n)$ such that from any set containing at least $N$ points it is possible to select $n$ points forming a convex polygon? There are two particular questions: (1) does the number $N$ exist? (2) If so, how is the least $N(n)$ determined? We give two proofs that the first question is to be answered in the affirmative. Both of them will give definite values for $N(n)$." How can you read that, and still ask how it relates to your question? It **is** your question!